# How to add tab-index for anchor tag through JavaScript dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wai-aria, tabindex

Currently i am  Working on Web Accessibility. In that i need to access my project fully on keyboard controls.I have tried a lot to to complete the task  and refer the W3c WAI-ARIA Concepts but cant able to done it.Some one guide me here pls if there is any tutorial is also fine for me.

Comment: Congratulations! You have somehow stumbled on to the internet but missed the existence of **Search Engines**! A quick search of the title of your question brings up a multitude of appropriate answers. Try doing some research before asking.

Comment: I'm flagging this to be closed because "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.". Please feel free to edit this question to make it on-topic

Answer (score 0):

Use the below javascript code to add tab index dynamically.

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
   links[i].tabIndex = i+1;
}
```